# Cloud service for team collaboration with per folder/file permissions and within my file explorer

Tags: windows, gratis, web-services, cloud-service, cloud

I hope you can help me. There are currently countless of cloud options out there, but I'm still one of the people, who barely use clouds overall, so I have no insight into the field. And googling for suggestions is a big problem, since most of the features I want are not well documented and not easy to search for with Google. So I'm here to ask for your suggestions.

### Purpose

I have a team of 6-10 people, who I want to share specific files with. Most important for me is that I have full control over the cloud service, so I can delete files without a history tracking it and so denying the access of it.

The purpose for this is to share to-do-list and other text files, hyperlinks, spreadsheets.

It's very important that my admins and my moderators see different files and that certain folders can be hidden to everyone. Which leads me to the most important point, it should be a file explorer style like Dropbox would offer, so it's syncing up and easier to manage.

### Needed Features

So the features I search are:

- having a cloud system which actually downloads the files (like
  Dropbox) not only browser cloud
- having file / permissions, so I can give my admins access to other files than the mods
- don't show all folders to everyone, for example I want to add a .git folder for version control of the files, which is hidden
- if Git doesn't work or if the cloud service has some version control for text and office files it would be great (so everyone can
  see changes)
- I don't need options to play like excel files natively in an web interface, it's fine if everyone needs the program
- it needs to be integrated in the FILE system of Windows and/or Mac
- other people should be able to create files as well, but I should have full permissions over them
- also storage is no factor, we will barely get over 2 GB of data

Free options are preferred, but to not limit my options too much you can suggest paid versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

u can use [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com). nextcloud support for collaborate